# How to add fields to the aspNetUser table in .NET Core 2.0 using the inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, migration

I use the aspNetUser table to store my users of
system, so I need to know which country and city belong to these, for this I added the following models City and country

```
public class Country : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} only can contain {1} characters length.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "# Cities")]
        public int NumberCities { get { return this.Cities == null ? 0 : this.Cities.Count; } }
    }

public class City : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Ciudad")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "el campo {0} solo puede contener {1} caracteres de largo.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and I add in my User class that it inherits from IdentityUser, a CityId field and a City object with the aim of introducing these fields to my aspNetUser table

[image: Database]

```
 public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "el campo {0} solo debe contener {1} caracteres de largo.")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Apellido")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "el campo {0} solo debe contener {1} caracteres de largo.")]
        public string Apellido { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Dirección")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "el campo {0} solo debe contener {1} caracteres de largo.")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public int CityId { get; set; }

        public City City { get; set; }

    }
```

The problem lies in my class SeaderDB.cs (Seed database) that fills the database every time I delete it to execute a migration, here is exactly where my program bursts! when assembling the User class and inserting it into the database

my seader.cs class verifies if there is a user admin .... if not, it creates it, but it is at the moment of assembling the user object where it falls

[image: Error]

SeedDB.CS:

```
 public async Task SeedAsync()
        {
            await this.context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

            await userHelper.CheckRoleAsync("Dios");
            await userHelper.CheckRoleAsync("Admin");
            await userHelper.CheckRoleAsync("User");

            var user = await userHelper.GetUserByEmailAsync("coambiado@ing.ucsc.cl");
            if (user == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    user = new User
                    {
                        Nombre = "Cristofher",
                        Apellido = "Ambiado",
                        Email = "coambiado@ing.ucsc.cl",
                        UserName = "coambiado@ing.ucsc.cl",
                        PhoneNumber = "+56958987975",
                        EmailConfirmed = true,
                        Address = "Calle Luna Calle Sol",
                        CityId = context.Countries.FirstOrDefault().Cities.FirstOrDefault().Id,
                        City = context.Countries.FirstOrDefault().Cities.FirstOrDefault()
                    };
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {

                }       

                var result = await userHelper.AddUserAsync(user, "fytitosk8");              
                if (result != IdentityResult.Success)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("No se pudo crear el usuario"); 
                }
                await userHelper.AddUserToRoleAsync(user, "Dios");
            }


            var isInRole = await userHelper.IsUserInRoleAsync(user, "Dios");
            if (!isInRole)
            {
                await userHelper.AddUserToRoleAsync(user, "Dios");
            }


            //AGREGAR PRODUCTOS
            if (!this.context.Productos.Any())
            {
                this.AddProductos("COMBO 1 + JUGO CITRICO",  user);
                this.AddProductos("ENSALADA CESAR + JUGO CITRICO", user);
                this.AddProductos("MENU VEGAN 1 + POSTRE",  user);
                this.AddProductos("MENU VEGAN 2 + POSTRE", user);

                await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            //AGREGAR PAISES
            if (!this.context.Countries.Any())
            {
                var cities = new List<City>();

                cities.Add(new City { Name = "Concepción" });
                cities.Add(new City { Name = "Santiago" });
                cities.Add(new City { Name = "Iquique" });
                cities.Add(new City { Name = "Valdivia" });

                this.context.Countries.Add(new Country
                {
                    Cities = cities,
                    Name = "Chile"
                });

                await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

        }
```

Can I use lamdas expressions to ask for the value of the CityId? What is happening with my code? Am I doing these changes well? the seader is creating the country and the cities, but is not able to obtain them under Linq instructions ... any help for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a user it is better to use a default value just like other fields. 
Instead of these lines of code;

```
CityId = context.Countries.FirstOrDefault().Cities.FirstOrDefault().Id,
                    City = context.Countries.FirstOrDefault().Cities.FirstOrDefault()
```

For example you can use this;

```
user = new User
                {
                    Nombre = "Cristofher",
                    Apellido = "Ambiado",
                    Email = "coambiado@ing.ucsc.cl",
                    UserName = "coambiado@ing.ucsc.cl",
                    PhoneNumber = "+56958987975",
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    Address = "Calle Luna Calle Sol",
                    CityId = 1,
                    City = new City { Id =1, Name = "Concepción" } 
                };
```

Comment: City is a property of type City which is related to User .... (it can not be a string), it is worth mentioning that its solution worked, and it is letting me compile.

Comment: Oo. I didn't pay attention. You are right. Then you can first build a city object and then add that. I'm going to correct my answer